# How do I find the source fork for a pull request from the Git command line?

Tags: git, command-line, pull-request

Our development team follows a fork-based development model, where each developer works on their own fork, and creates pull requests into the central repository for each feature. I can fetch all pull requests targeted at a given repo using a command like:

```
git fetch +refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

This puts all of the pull requests for that remote into the `.git/refs/remotes/origin/pr` directory, for example, `.git/refs/remotes/origin/pr/7217`, which is a text file containing a single commit hash.

How can I find the source fork for this pull request, using the Git command line? I'd like to find the developer who opened the pull request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting this as "how to find the first new commit on a branch". To that I would combine `git merge-base` to get the first common commit between master and the pr branch then use `git rev-list` to find the new commits in the branch

```
git rev-list $(git merge-base master origin/pr/7217)..origin/pr/7217 | tail -1
```

The `rev-list` will print all new shas on the pr branch so piping it to `tail -1` gives you just the first. You could run `git show` or one of the other commands to see it.

If you need to script something that should get you there.

If you aren't writing a script and just want to see all of the commits on the PR you could change `rev-list` to `log` and get rid of the pipe to tail. That would give you a formatted list of the PR's commits

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should set user name and user email first.

```
git config user.name xxxx    
git config user.email xxxx@xxx
```

Comment: I want to find out who filed a given pull request, say PR #7217, from the Git command line. The solution above would associate my user name and email with my commits. Thanks for the response.